# incorrect Subversion info in mercurial changeset after svn convert

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-convert

I used hg convert to migrate my svn repository to Mecurial. It has been successful on the most part. However, i have one svn repository that is just a folder of word files and this displays undesired information in the 'Subversion:' property in the changeset details in TortoiseHg.

For my other projects, this property displays something like 'utils@182' where this information refers to the repository (utils) and revision (182) from my source svn repository. I think this is mostly luck on my part because the repositories tended to have a folder that contained all the files within the .svn location, for example:

myreposlocation.com / main.svn / utils

the luck part being that either i had created a subfolder to structure projects within one repository or an extra folder created by visual studio.

Anyway, the problem comes when i convert my project that has no subfolder and the url is somethng like this:

myreposlocation.com / docs.svn

whats happening is in the Subversion: property details, it puts the revision number (i assume from the svn repository) and then makes an assumption that this points to a revision within the current repository and adds the changeset of that revision and also a link, just like the parent / child properties do.
This is incorrect and misleading. Ideally i would like it to display as before 'docs@16' or show nothing at all.

Any ideas of how i can add a config switch to the convert or remove this detail after conversion? The commits are all draft on the target repository and i can recreate it as many times as i like.

I tried to add some images but cannot as i'm new here, long time reader, first time poster ;)

Thanks

av

Comment: I solved this. the reason behind this is that svn is normally structured with \trunk \branch etc. (but in my case it wasnt) and the convert is using the trunk name in the changeset information. Anyway, the way i did it in the end was to write a custom change script as detailed on the https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Subversion page. If anyone has the same problem, i can let you know a bit more.